# Entity Framework - Simple Inject use Interfaces as Models

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dependency-injection, ioc-container, simple-injector

I'm trying to implement my Context like this

```
IDbSet<IRoom> Rooms { get; set; }
```

However EF doesn't support interfaces.

I've the following Service which may create `IRoom`/`Room`:

```
public virtual void CreateSamples()
{
    Room room = new Room();
    room.Encrypted = true;
    room.Token = Guid.NewGuid();
    room.Name = "teste-" + room.Token.ToString();
    room.NoTracking = true;
    room.Private = true;
    room.UserId = this.membership.CurrentUser;
    room.CreatedBy = room.ModifiedBy = this.membership.CurrentUser;

    this.context.Rooms.Add(room);
    this.context.SaveChanges();
}
```

This "EF Interface Model" came because i want to replace

`Room room = new Room();`

with

`IRoom room = ObjectFactory.Create<IRoom>();`

PS: Behind the scenes `ObjectFactory.Create<>` calls the Injector Container and gets the object using `GetInstance<>`

The problem here is that my context accepts `Room` but not `IRoom` since the declaration is:

`IDbSet<Room> Rooms { get; set; }`

If it isn't clear `this.context.Rooms` is my `IDbSet<Room>`

Is it possible to achieve what I want?

I'm thinking about creating a UnitOfWork which receives the interface and then goes to the injector container and tries to get the correspondent type. Am I thinking right?

Comment: What is the reason you would want to do this, what benefit does using an interface have in this situation? I recommend you use classes the way that EF was designed. Use class `Room` instead, these are POCO classes and do not have to contain any functionality if you do not want them to. You can still apply IRoom to Room if you really want to just not as a type in EF types like DbSet or DbContext where EF expects a class.

Comment: But what's the point of having `IRoom` if you can't use it since all the methods will need `Room` to do CRUD in the DB?

Comment: But yes, I didn't stop to think, but it actually doesn't feel right. Probably I will forget this and delete all my model interfaces

Comment: Side note: I went down a similar road once (forced on my by my boss at the time) to use interfaces everywhere even when it made no sense . We were using EF4 at the time with ObjectContext so all models that we used in EF had interfaces and exposed those interfaces and I still have to live with that code. It was/is and is a mess and there were loads of unexpected side effects and pretty much 0 benefits. I really do not recommend this approach at all.

Comment: I agree with @Igor. Interfaces are meant to abstract behavior, but your EF models are data containers. Hiding them behind an abstraction usually has no benefit. Can you tell me what is your reasoning for placing them behind interfaces?

Comment: I was thinking about releasing the source code of the application without my SDK (Core Logic) which then could be extended only trough DI including database, but well, database shouldn't be closed or otherwise it would be a pain